# How to connect VMWare Linux Machines using RadminVPN on a Windows hosts?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, vpn, vmware

I have 10 friends in different cities, I created a LAN using RadminVPN and we all connected to the same private network. RadminVPN provides similar capabilities as LogMeIn Hamachi.

Each one of us has a **Windows host** and an **Ubuntu guest** system installed in VMWare Workstation.
RadminVPN client can only be installed on Windows and provides each member of the network with a unique **IP: 26.x.x.x** (Mask: 255.0.0.0, Gateway: 26.0.0.1), with no option of manual IP selection.

How do we need to configure network settings in VMWare Workstation in order to be able to communicate with each other from our Ubuntu machines?

This is what I tried:

1. I thought that creating a bridged connection to the RadminVPN
   adapter would work, but Ubuntu machines couldn't get their own IP
   addresses as RadminVPN doesn't act like DHCP server.
2. Using default NAT, on the other hand, allowed me to ping Windows
   host of the other network members, but as I understand, they would
   not be able to communicate with my Ubuntu machine since 26.x.x.x
   still belongs to my Windows host.

So how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually go with the option #1, the only thing you would need to assign IP address manually. In your case, choose the IP not assigned on all machines on the network and assign it on VM (e.g. 26.0.0.135/8)

Comment: I can now ping the Ubuntu machine from my Windows host, but other Windows hosts on the network can't do that. Do I need to set up a gateway or anything else?
Here is my ifconfig on Ubuntu: http://prntscr.com/sqokgp

Comment: Can you ping Windows hosts from the Ubuntu VM? I am not sure how radmin actually creates VPN (never worked with it). Alternatively, I've found a software, which can run on Linux directly. Might help, https://www.zerotier.com/

Comment: No, I can't ping other Windows hosts. Thank you for sharing the link, I will try that software.